# Firebase Messasing - Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Object' in type cast

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my mobile application that I developed with Flutter, I wrote the following code:

```
  void sendMessage() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.sendMessage(
      to: "enQMEpfVSIiDjnSVnc5s-P:APA91bGEEO-Hct8fEMAINm8NzmLrIF3PhcJ44KYIfcU4fJFyzGWGgaqIrJAlcV_IA7xnu_0GrvOFQlgBAg7n7JhFqz_JeLn1K1O5yC783WzwSJJYMrbCGED1U5pNNYZJTUdEU0v9MTcg",
      data: {"body": "body text", "title": "title test"},
    );
  }
```

Error:

```
E/flutter (23124): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Object' in type cast
```

How to solve the problem? Thanks for help.